# ubuntu 18.04 no more IP after i removed yaml file from /etc/netplan

Tags: dhcp, netplan

I had ubuntu 18.04 server with cloud-init still DHCP enabled IP address.

I added yaml file to /etc/netplan and removed the file already there (think it was `50-cloud-init.yaml`), but now i can't get the network up anymore

This is the basic example used:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

and `netplan --debug apply` doesn't show much strange?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2uE3.jpg

How to proceed and check what is wrong? really annoying if you can't ssh :)

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that the interface name is `eno1` not `enp3s0`

Comment: indeed, i never made up from the tutorials that these 2 needed to match. Maybe it's just so obvious, but i missed it.

Answer (score 0):

The interface name from your screenshot is `eno1`, not `enp3s0`.

The tutorials and examples for Netplan are just that - examples.  You need to rename the network interfaces to actually match the names of the interfaces on your computer, otherwise it won't work properly.  Replace `enp3s0` from the example with `eno1`, and then try and run `netplan --debug apply`.  You'll see that it properly applies the configuration and you'll have an IP again.